# How can I rotate disclosure indicator on tap?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to rotate the disclosure indicator when I tap on my cell

I think this might be done with `didSelectRowAt` but don't know how to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you will need to use an icon. The disclosure indicator of native cells can't be rotated because you don't have access to the icon.

Try to get an disclosure icon, put it as an image in your cell then you can do anything with the image.